# Java Swing render html align text on the right side

Tags: java, html, css, swing, jtextpane

I'm currently working on a chat GUI with java and I'm trying to use the html css option with JTextPane.

I'm not familiar with html / css so it was a bit hard but I managed to get the result I wanted except from 1 thing.

[image: My first result]

The thing is, I want the blue chat to be on the right side of the screen, like 30% of the screen is empty and then there is the blue part.

Here is a photoshop of what I'm trying to obtain :

[image]

Here is my java code :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class FenetreRenduHtml extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel p_content;
    private JTextArea ta_css;
    private JTextArea ta_html_body;
    private JTextPane tp_html;

    private void renderHtml(String html)
    {
        tp_html.setContentType("text/plain");
        tp_html.putClientProperty(JEditorPane.HONOR_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES, true);
        tp_html.setContentType("text/html");
        tp_html.setText("<html>"+html+"</html>");
    }

    private void renderHtml(String html_body, String style)
    {
        if (style==null) renderHtml(html_body);
        else renderHtml("<head><style>\n"+style+"\n</style></head><body>"+html_body+"</body>");
    }

    private void doHtmlRender()
    {
        String
            t_html_body = ta_html_body.getText(),
            t_css = ta_css.getText();
        renderHtml(t_html_body, t_css);
    }

    public FenetreRenduHtml()
    {
        setTitle("Test d'affichage en HTML");
        Dimension d = new Dimension(800, 600);
        setSize(d);
        setMinimumSize(d);
        setLocation(new Point(200, 100));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        p_content = new JPanel();
        p_content.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(p_content);
        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
        gbl.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        gbl.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        p_content.setLayout(gbl);

        Font f_mono = new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 14);
        Border text_border = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4);

        JLabel l_css = new JLabel("Contenu CSS");
        {
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            p_content.add(l_css, gbc);
        }

        JScrollPane sp_css = new JScrollPane();
        {
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            p_content.add(sp_css, gbc);
        }

        ta_css = new JTextArea();
        ta_css.setFont(f_mono);
        ta_css.setBorder(text_border);
        ta_css.setText("/* Style CSS ici */");
        sp_css.setViewportView(ta_css);

        JLabel l_html = new JLabel("HTML source");
        {
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 2;
            p_content.add(l_html, gbc);
        }

        JScrollPane sp_html_body = new JScrollPane();
        {
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 3;
            p_content.add(sp_html_body, gbc);
        }

        ta_html_body = new JTextArea();
        ta_html_body.setFont(f_mono);
        ta_html_body.setBorder(text_border);
        sp_html_body.setViewportView(ta_html_body);

        JButton b_disp_html = new JButton("Afficher \u2192"); // "Afficher ->"
        b_disp_html.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            { doHtmlRender(); }
        });
        {
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 4;
            p_content.add(b_disp_html, gbc);
        }

        JLabel l_disp_html = new JLabel("HTML affiché");
        {
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            p_content.add(l_disp_html, gbc);
        }

        JScrollPane sp_html = new JScrollPane();
        {
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.gridheight = 3;
            p_content.add(sp_html, gbc);
        }

        tp_html = new JTextPane();
        sp_html.setViewportView(tp_html);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                FenetreRenduHtml frame = new FenetreRenduHtml();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the css code I put in the GUI  :

```
h1 {
    background : solid #3b82f7; 
    font-size : 15 ; 
    font-weight : normal;
    color : #FFFFFF; 
    padding : 2px; 
}
h2 {
    background : solid #3c3c3c; 
    font-size : 15 ; 
    font-weight : normal;
    color : #FFFFFF;
    padding : 2px; 

}
```

And here is the html code I put in the GUI :

```
<html>
<div>
    <div align = right width=70%>
        <h1>
            Hello, i'm trying to put this on the right side of the screen but i can't manage to do it
        </h1>
    </div>
    
</div>

<div align=left width=70%>
    <h2>
        And this is supposed to stay here so it's okay 
    </h2>
</div>
</html>
```

@hfontanez **here is what I got with your code** :

[image]

Comment: It could make sense to [validate the HTML](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) before wondering why it does not behave as expected. The same goes for CSS. Having said that, Swing support for either is very patchy. Swing's HTML rendering engine understands a subset of **HTML 3.2** elements and only a smattering of CSS.

Comment: Yeah I know that, and that's why I came to ask for help because I'm no master in Swing's HTML & CSS. 

I just validate both langage, it seems correct.

Comment: *" I just validate both langage, it seems correct."* So why did I see 7 errors when validating the HTML?

Comment: Because you just copy pasted the code you see in the html and css part, there is code in the java section, function "html render", and I used the code @hfontanez gave me so it's s bit different mate :)

Comment: BTW: See also this page related to {CSS support](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/html/CSS.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have totally changed my answer. This will be my last try.

### HTML with Styling

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>YOUR TITLE</title>
<style>
.parent{
  font:         14px/1.23 sans-serif;
  display:      table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width:        100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 10px;
}

/* ROWS */

.message{
  display: table-row;
}

/* ALL CELLS */

.message > *{
  position:   relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display:    table-cell;
}

/* MESSAGE CELLS */

.message p {
  color:      #ffffff;
  border-radius:4px;
  padding: 12px 14px;
  background-color: #3c3c3c;
  width: 300px;
}
.message.left p {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 36px 0 0;
}
.message.right p {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 0 36px;
  background-color: #3b82f7;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent">

      <div class="message left">
        <p>Any luck?</p>
      </div>

      <div class="message right">
        <p> Hello, I'm trying to put this on the right side of the screen but i can't manage to do it</p>
      </div>

      <div class="message left">
        <p>Well... Seems to be working!</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="message right">
        <p>AWESOME!</p>
      </div>
      
    </div> 
</html>
```

### Result

[image]

If this doesn't work, then it is definitely an issue with Swing.

Comment: It doesn't work :(, I tried with and without the right alignement and with and without the width precision but nothing works, probably because it's not juste html and it's basic html (like 4 I think with CSS1). 
Do you know how to do it in that case ? Thanks

Comment: I am going to edit my answer.

Comment: All of the styling should be done in the CSS. Think about regular programming. You want to encapsulate all of the styling attributes in the class. That includes font size, font family, padding, alignment, etc.

Comment: Hey ! It still doesn't work, I edited my question, at the bottom of it you can see the result of your code

Comment: I think your Swing code is overwriting the CSS styling. Not sure, but I think the issue is with the `GridBagConstraints `

Comment: hum that's annoying, I tried with an other layout and it didn't change a thing

Comment: I validated the HTML using Andrew Thompson's link. I will include the new HTML in my answer.

Comment: unfortunately, the result doesn't change with the validated html, it's the same than the one I show you with your first code ..

Comment: Then the problem must be with the Swing code.

Comment: that's what I thought too, but it add "<head><style>\n"+style+"\n</style></head><body>"+html_body+"</body>"
and then "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>"+html+"</html>" so everything is like the code you put in your edit..

Comment: @Madar I think I got it. About to update my answer. This will be my last try.

Comment: well this one is really not working unfortunately, there is only the text, it looks like there is no CSS at all, I think Swing's HTML is too limited to put code like this.. 
Well anyway, thank u for your help mate

Comment: @Madar of course, you can change the font, margins, etc. to fit your needs

Comment: @Madar Seems to be Swing. You can see from the image the HTML rendered perfectly in Chrome.

Comment: @Madar I just thought of something. Replace the `background` to whatever you were using before. I think it was `background: solid #COLOR`

Comment: does not change anything unfortunately